# In a custom UITableViewCell Hide/Unhide UILabel on Button Click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom table view cell with a button and a label.
Label value is fetched from NSMutableArray and label is hidden by default. On button click I want to unhide label of the same cell. Thanks in Advance.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
selCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"beautyIdentifier"];
if (selCell == nil) {

    selCell = [[MDTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"beautyIdentifier"] ;
}
selCell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.878 green:0.878 blue:0.878 alpha:1];

    NSObject *labelData=[[reqSubcat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"subcategoryName"];
    NSString *label=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",labelData];

    //Check Button
    checkButton=[[UIButton alloc] init];
    [checkButton setFrame:CGRectMake(20,25,30, 30)];
    checkButton.layer.cornerRadius = checkButton.frame.size.width /2;
    checkButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
    checkButton.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    checkButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.f;
    [checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBox:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [checkButton setTitle:label forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkButton setTitleColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    checkButton.tag=indexPath.row;
    [selCell addSubview:checkButton];

NSString *cost=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"₹ %@",[costArray     objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        CGSize stringsize1 = [cost sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:
                                                            [UIFont systemFontOfSize:40.0f]}];
        costLabel=[[UILabel alloc] init];
        [costLabel setText:cost];
        [costLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(250,20,stringsize1.width, 40)];
        costLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura" size:25];
        costLabel.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.153 green:0.239 blue:0.294 alpha:1];
        costLabel.tag=indexPath.row;
        costLabel.hidden=NO;
        [selCell.contentView addSubview:costLabel];
}

- (void)checkBox:(UIButton *)sender
{
   // resetTitle=@"";

NSLog(@"%@",resetTitle);
NSLog(@"%ld",(long)sender.tag);


if ([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"✓"])
{

    sender.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor] ;
    [sender setTitle:resetTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    sender.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;


}
else
{
     resetTitle=sender.titleLabel.text;
    NSLog(@"%@",resetTitle);

    sender.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0.839 blue:0.314 alpha:1] ;
    [sender setTitle:@"✓" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura" size:25]];
    [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    sender.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

    }

}
```

Comment: post your code, what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't add any views to cell inside

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

Instead, add the views in the cell's init method. (MDTableViewCell in your case)

Second, the button's target should be set within cell, and when it's tapped you will be redirected to the cell, where you can hide the cell's label.

Comment: The Cell I am using is from Machine Design Library. Will this solution work for that? I am reusing the same at many other View Controllers.

Comment: Yes. This'll work. You just need to modify the ```- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style
              reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier``` of ```MDTableViewCell``` and add your label, button and button's target there.